# firebase functions std::bad_alloc

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm seeing the following error in my terminal when trying to hit a firebase endpoint locally:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc`

Here is what is seen in the firebase-debug.log:

```
[info] >  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc {"user":"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc"}}
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to what this is?

Comment: Have you already seen [this open issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1042)? It sounded similar to your problem. Could you update your post as well and provide more information including your environment and the full stack trace of the error?